# disable push animation in Xcode storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I have created two viewcontrollers and added a button to viewcontroller1, in storyboard. When I push this button viewcontroller2 is shown (this is done by connecting viewcontroller1 with a push to viewcontroller2). This works fine but I would like to remove the animation when  viewcontroller2 is pushed.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, marked the segue between the views -> changed style to custom and created a segue class.

Then i followed this tutorial: http://i5insights.com/?p=744

Comment: tutorial is not there anymore :(